# How to write JPQL query to get all the views and indexes from Oracle/postgreSQL DB

Tags: oracle, postgresql, jpql

Hi every one,
            I have a requirement to get all the views and indexes from Oracle/PostgreSQL DB

Here I have written one query like below to get all views

```
  SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where table_schema = 'public'
```

But that is postgreSQL dependent query right. Because in Oracle, information_schema was implemented differently so i thought to write jpql query but i dont know how to write.
Could anybody please help me out!

Thanks & regards,
Sridhar Kosna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. JPQL is only able to query mapped entities. Not database tables. You'll need to use SQL, and if you need to support multiple databases, have one DAO per database and use the appropriate DAO based on the used database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you suggest me how can i write the query to make it as DB independent?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Every database has its own way of storing and querying the views and indices.

Comment: Okay. so instead of making it as independent of DB I need to write native query based on the DB right!